# Force rebuild of system.applicationHost/sites in IISExpress applicationhost.config?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-express

Is there a way to force a rebuild of the system.applicationHost/sites section in the IISExpress applicationhost.config ?

I have a project that has a hard coded Project Url.

#### Repeat Steps

1. Debug the project in Visual Studio.
2. Stop the debugger
3. Debug a different branch of the same project in a different instance of Visual Studio.

#### Result

IISExpress will point to the first branch.

#### Workaround

The only way that I can get the system.applicationHost/sites section to update is to close all copies of Visual Studio, and reopen the branch I want to debug. I does not work to just close IISExpress and rerun the debugger.

Here is the Web tab of the Project Properties:

[image: is configured]